# Icons are not perfectly centered

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic UI icons and trying to compose multiple icons to create a new one. When using big icons, it's pretty nice but when using small icons, it appears the icons are not perfecly centered.

Below, we see that the more the icon is small, the more the horizontal alignment is incorrect

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/components/icon.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <i class="huge icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="big icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="large icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the predifined margin added to circle outline class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small margin defined by default creating this issue, simply remove it:

```
i.icons .icon:first-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Full code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/components/icon.css">
<style>
i.icons .icon:first-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
  
    <i class="huge icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="big icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="large icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>

    <i class="icons">
      <i class="circle outline icon"></i>
      <i class="tiny times  icon"></i>
    </i>
  </body>
</html>
```